# windows phone 8 background agent running

Tags: windows-phone-8

Background agent for my windows phone app is running even if my solution and mobile app both stop running but background agent is running   How It will be possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question, running when the app is not is the very purpose of background agents

Comment: I'm monitoring the app even if my app is not running in my mobile or in my system. I wont even log in to my app but still my background agent is running.I have given the time interval 1 min but for debug mode is running every 1 min but for release mode it varies.

Comment: Your background agent is running even when your App is not running because that's exactly what it was designed to do. You are probably looking for a thread, not a background agent.